# SQL Query comparison (Use as variable)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM postcodelatlng, shops WHERE shops.postcode=postcodelatlng.postcode;

SELECT * FROM postcodelatlng, tesco WHERE tesco.postcode=postcodelatlng.postcode;
```

idea is that I would like to use **lat** and **lng** from first query and use it as variable as lat1 and lng1

and the take second query and use the same way to get lat2 and lng2

Finally i should have like ($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) (Start point vs End point)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking sth like:

```
SELECT *
FROM postcodelatlng
INNER JOIN tesco ON tesco.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode
WHERE postcodelatlng.lat IN (
        SELECT lat
        FROM postcodelatlng
        INNER JOIN shops
        WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode
        )
    AND postcodelatlng.lng IN (
        SELECT lng
        FROM postcodelatlng
        INNER JOIN shops
        WHERE shops.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode
        )
```